# tr:selectoneradio valuechange listener not working on veryfirst time value change

Tags: jsf, trinidad, valuechangelistener

I have a select one radio button:

```
<tr:selectOneRadio id="ViaRadio"
                   value="#{backingBean.viaSelected}"
                   autoSubmit="true"
                   valuePassThru="true"
                   required="true"
                   layout="horizontal" 
                   immediate="true"
                   simple="true"
                   valueChangeListener="#{backingBean.viaChangeListener}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.viaOptions}"/>
</tr:selectOneRadio>
```

In the backing bean I have a value change listener, just to refresh the below content based on the radio button selected. Also in the constructor I set the default value:

```
viaSelected="One"
```

So initially "One" radio will be selected and content is rendered for that One value. But when I select "Two" radio button, value change listener method is not called and panel refresh also did not happen. But there after what ever value I select, it works perfectly. Means when I change from default value to any other value for "first time" it is not working as expected. But there after it is working. I tried with `immediate="true" required="true" valuePassThru="true"` but nothing helped.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691594/valuechangelistener-for-trselectbooleanradio-is-not-working-the-expected-way is related here.

Comment: For the above question, the is it's working only when the radio button's button(circle) part is selected, not when text part is selected. You can try this. I'm not sure this could be of any help to you.