# Clicking text in tr:selectbooleanradio not generating valueChangeEvent

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, trinidad

In my JSF 2.0(MyFaces 2.1.10, Trinidad 2.1.0 Version)Application, I need to use tr:selectbooleanradio in my page to achieve the functionality that my page requires.

In the below code, the default values of todaySelected and tomorrowSelected are 'false'. The issue is, once page loads, when I select 'today', the valueChangeToday is not getting called.(I believe it should call as default value of todaySelected is false and submitted value is true). When I select tomorrow, valueChangeToday is getting called and valueChangeTomorrow is not getting called. Likewise, things are happening only after the next selection, which makes my entire functionality working reversely.

I believe in both the cases, the submitted value is not going in correctly. But I couldn't understand why?!

FYI -tr:selectOneRadio is working perfectly, but I rely on booleanRadio.

The scope of the page bean is View(though I believe it's not a problem and request scope is performing similiarly). I'd appreciate any suggestions to resolve this issue or core component alternatives for this issue.

```
<tr:selectBooleanRadio group="groupDays"
selected="#{displayoverrideamountbean.todaySelected}"
id="todayRadio" text="Today" 
valueChangeListener="#{displayoverrideamountbean.valueChangeToday}"                                                 
autoSubmit="true">
</tr:selectBooleanRadio>

<tr:selectBooleanRadio group="groupDays"
selected="#{displayoverrideamountbean.tomorrowSelected}"
id="tomorrowRadio" text="Tomorrow" 
valueChangeListener="#{displayoverrideamountbean.valueChangeTomorrow}"                                                  
autoSubmit="true">
</tr:selectBooleanRadio>
```

Comment: Yeah. My faces 2.1.10

Comment: Trinidad 2.1.0 Version.

Comment: it is in maven... removed my comment

Comment: Found the issue, still looking for an answer, the issue is happening only when we select the text part of the radio button. When we click the button part(round button), it's working perfectly. As of now, I'm not sure whether this is company's own code to select the button text is selected (Or) trinidad feature.

Comment: Modified subject accordingly